# Where did War Machine’s new suit come from?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*,

> After the Avengers HQ gets leveled

War Machine exits his suit and leaves it behind. Later that same scene, he shows up in what seems like a bigger suit with different coloring.

Where'd it come from and when? I don't recall any other scenes that might've explained it.

> Except possibly Tony's opening scene but that suit is clearly being worn by Pepper at the same time as War Machine has his new armor.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Full credit to [u\GarMek over on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/ciwrnf/detail_you_can_see_the_new_eg_war_machine_suit_on/?utm_content=media&utm_medium=post_embed&utm_name=a13089052ecf40be8ddf25169ceac4b6&utm_source=embedly&utm_term=ciwrnf) for this. We see the new suit lying in the background next to Scott when he emerges from the rubble and before he goes to help Rhodey, Rocket and Smart Hulk out. Having watched the scenes back this happens at ~02:04:00 in the Disney+ version of the film.

[image: A back shot of Scott shrunken down as Ant-Man amongst the rubble, the top of Rhodey's suit is seen in the background]

And if it wasn't obvious enough that this is the suit Rhodey wears during the battle (as the old one was broken and he'd left it behind under the water) compare the suit he's wearing before Smart Hulk's snap and the one when Giant-Man emerges from the ground with him. Note the red under colour and around the collar of the new suit to the suit above that we see behind Scott.

[image: Rhodey and Scott stand side by side suited up in the Avengers HQ room preparing for Smart Hulk's snap] [image: Giant-Man in the background having just emerged from the ground with Smart Hulk, Rhodey and Rocket; Rhodey hovers in the air in front in the new armour with Rocket on his shoulder wielding his weapon]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

---

I don’t think it is ever explained. However, it would seem logical that it is just another suit for War Machine that is stored at Avengers HQ for some other function. Tony still has the Hulkbuster suit for fighting Hulk so I’d imagine War Machine’s extra suit is stored there for some other function. This makes some sense as it is more heavy duty.

It’s worth noting that Rhodey was meant to have two suits in *Avengers: Infinity War* but this was cut down so this might also be a holdover from then.

> "Originally, Rhodey was going to have two different armors in this movie. And then this ultimately got narrowed down to one armor, so the best elements in both armors were combined into one," said concept illustrator Phil Saunders in The Art of Avengers: Infinity War. "We really wanted to give him a much more advanced look than what he had had in the previous movie to keep up a little bit with the leap from the Mark 47 to Mark 50 for Iron Man.
>
> "So I went with a much more sophisticated stealth geometry and breakup of the form language. I also gave him a far more extensive package of weaponry than he had ever previously had."
>
> <sub>[Comic Book, 'Avengers: Endgame' Figure Reveals War Machine's Armor](https://comicbook.com/marvel/2019/02/11/avengers-endgame-war-machine-armor/)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think if you see the scene where Ant-Man was responding to Rhodey call
behind him seems to have the new armor laying down

Comment: Welcome to the site. You may want to take our [tour] and visit the [help] to see what kind of answers we are looking for. As it stands this does not really answer the question.

Comment: Hi Gusion, this answer could be improved by including a screenshot of the scene.

Answer (score -5):

In the film, as Hulk is holding up the debris and Rhodey saving Rocket; Hulk yells “Veronica” just before the screen changes back to the battlefield. I think that’s where the new suite came from.